# Seaborn lineplot logarithmic scale

Tags: python, seaborn, line-plot

I'm having a problem with adding a logarithmic X-axis to my plot. I want to show results based on the sample size with methods `A`, `B` and `C`.

My dataframe `result`:

```
            A         B         C
15   0.733333  0.613333  0.733333
30   0.716667  0.693333  0.766667
59   0.733684  0.678485  0.745763
118  0.796667  0.726087  0.779661
236  0.817862  0.788333  0.838983
470  0.832125  0.814468  0.836170
```

What I'm trying to make work:

```py
sample_count = np.around(np.logspace(math.log10(15),math.log10(470),6))
sample_count = sample_count.astype(int)

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
g_results=sns.lineplot(data=results,dashes=0,markers=['o','o','o'])
g_results.set(xticks=sample_count)
g_results.set(xscale='log')
```

However the result is not what I exactly want, as the ticks are completely gone:

[image: current output]

Without the last `xscale` line it looks like this, which is the linear scale of course, but this time with the correct ticks:

[image: current output without xscale]

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image: desired output]

How do I get my desired output?

Comment: The title of this question should be changed to indicate that _only_ the `x` axis is talked about here, I came for the `y` axis, to no avail.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First set the scale for the x-axis to logarithmic and then set xticks and labels as you want.

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
g_results=sns.lineplot(data=results,dashes=0,markers=['o','o','o'])
g_results.set(xscale='log')
g_results.set(xticks=sample_count)
g_results.set(xticklabels=sample_count)
```

This gives you this result:

[image: resulting figure]

Note that I'm using `sample_count` as defined with the logarithmic scale:

```
sample_count = np.around(np.logspace(math.log10(15),math.log10(470),6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting the xticklabels as in @Davide Anghileri's answer, you can also format the tick values as a number using `matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
ax = sns.lineplot(data=results, dashes=0, markers=['o','o','o'])
ax.set(xscale='log', xticks=[15, 30, 59, 118, 236, 470])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
```

[image: result]

---

If you want to log-scale the y-axis, it works exactly the same; simply use `yaxis` instead of `xaxis` and `yscale` instead of `xscale`.

```py
data = pd.Series([15, 30, 59, 118, 236, 470])

ax = sns.lineplot(data=data)
ax.set(yscale='log', yticks=data)               # <--- logscale y-axis / set tick locations
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter()) # <--- format y-axis tick values
```